# How can I index all remaining items programatically?

Tags: 7, search

I'm just using the stock Drupal 7 search. Is there a function to index all the unindexed content from my module? And re-indexing? I haven't found this yet if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is `exec("drush search-index");`.